# Azure Front Door is routing only to one origin all the times

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

We have a Azure Front Door which has two origins .

But the problem here is the 2nd one has some issues , the application failed to start

so we disabled it through front origin group and when we hit the front door it shows the app failed to start error instead of going to other origin which is working.

Then we stopped the app service for 2nd one and tried to hit the front door then we get the error for Error 403 - This web app is stopped

what it tells s its still going to 2nd one .
Please let me if anybody faces the same issue

Comment: is the front door actually showing the 2nd backend as healthy? look into the metrics for the origin health

Answer (score 0):

> The Error 403 - This web app is stopped

1. This error may cause If your open public API is restricted from public access on Azure App Service. Your application's IP address that you are using to access the app service is not whitelisted or calls may be blocking.

   - As per [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) Check your access restriction rules in your portal

***Go to azure portal -> app -> Networking ->Access Restriction -> Configure Access Restrictions***

[image]

- Try adding 0.0.0.0/0 and granting access to everyone. Later, based on your needs, you can impose limits. It could have an effect if you receive banned calls before authorized calls.

[image]

2. Front Door considers all backends in a backend pool to be healthy even if health probes for any one of them fail, and traffic is distributed evenly across them all. Please refer [Health probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/health-probes#how-front-door-determines-backend-health)

   - Check your Priority By default, ***Front Door sends traffic only to the top priority backends***
   - Check your parameter uses a default ***weight of 50***
   - Try to put two backends in the same backend pool both should be availability then you can stop one backend. Choose backends with a range of least latency. ***The latency sensitivity property is by default set to 0, which means that the request will always be forwarded to the fastest backend.***

3.Try to disable `EnforceCertificateNameCheck` from the Azure portal and while adding to Orgin check whether you are enable `Cerficate subject name validation` must be ***enable***  for [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/troubleshoot-issues) this issue.

4.Try to add virtual directory /path in your app service by this [Azure front Door routing not working throws error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588983/azure-front-door-routing-rule-not-working-throws-e.html) credits by ***GitaraniSharmaMSFT-4262***

For your Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door#prerequisites

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods

Answer (score 0):

we un associated the existing orgin-group.
Created a new orignin-group and updated and  started working again.
Assumption is the orgingroup got corrupted due to some reason